# Replace repeated char with something else in a string

Tags: c#

I need help to figure out a logic:

So, let's say I have a string, and whenever there is a Char repeated inside that `string`, I need to replace it with a (`Char` + `sequence of number`).

For example:

Original String: `"abcdefgabfabc"`

Expected output: `"abcdefga2b2f2a3b3c2"`

> > 'a' occurs 3 times, so the first 'a' remains as 'a', but the second 'a' becomes 'a2', and the third 'a' becomes 'a3' and the same goes to other chars like b, b2, b3...

Comment: Hints: a `StringBuilder` and a `Dictionary` from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "abcdefgabfabc";
var chars = str.Select((c, index) =>
        {
            int count = str.Substring(0, index).Count(x => c == x);
            if (count > 0) return c.ToString() + (count+1);
            else return c.ToString();
        }).SelectMany(c => c).ToArray();
var result = new string(chars); // abcdefga2b2f2a3b3c2
```

Comment: That won't be efficient on long strings, but still, quite elegant. :)

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a `Dictionary` of letters and the # of occurrences of each letter
2. Create a `StringBuilder` to store the output
3. Loop through the input string letter by letter
4. Output the letter to the new string
5. If a letter is not in the dictionary, add it as the key with a '1' as the value
6. If a letter is already in the dictionary, increase the value by 1 and append the value to the output string

Comment: I was just working on writing that when your answer popped up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var foundChars = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var c in originalString)
{
    var count = 0;

    if (!foundChars.TryGetValue(c, out count)
    {
        foundChars.Add(c, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        count += 1;
        foundChars[c] = count;
    }

    stringBuilder.Append(c);
    if (count > 0) stringBuilder.Append(count);
}
```

Note that while less pretty this will be more performant than LINQ based solutions and be retrocompatible with .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use LINQ to iterate over each character, and then keep a counter of each one you encounter along the way.

For example..

```
var count = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var string = "abcdefabcdef";
var result = "";

string.Select().Each(c => {
    if (count.ContainsKey(c)) 
        count.Add(c, 1);
    else
        count[c]++;
    result += count[c] > 1? c + count[c] : c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers suffers from being `O(n^2)` ([Selman22](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838110/174574), [Stumblor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838301/174574)) or `O(n*log n)` ([Chrono1981](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838094/174574)) even though a `O(n)` solution is simple. The right solution is really what [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21838055/174574) and I hinted to. Here it goes:

```
var input = "abcdefgabfabc";
var counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var c in input)
{
    int count;
    counts.TryGetValue(c, out count);  // If "counts" doesn't have the key, then count will be 0
    counts[c] = ++count;

    sb.Append(c);

    if (count > 1)
        sb.Append(count);
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: What am I missing? Aside from checking the return value of `TryGetValue` and using a `SortedDictionary`, my code is almost identical to yours.