# Formatting the string by rewriting the delimiters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm dealing with some legacy data, where they store each record in one huge/large string (one string = one record)

In each string, they split the data in some sort of delimiters, but each of them actually defines a meaning, for example: \vToyota\cBlue\cRed\cWhite\s200mph\oAndrew\oJohn

\v means vehicle, \c is color, \s is speed \o is Owner... something like that

My task requires me to reformat the data so that if there are multiple fields of one characteristic, I have to rewrite it as: (for example) \vToyota\cBlue\c2Red\c3White\s200mph\oAndrew\o2John

> Edited: Alright. @DarrenYoung's suggestions works! Now I have an array of vToyota cBlue cRed cWhite s200mph oAndrew oJohn. I tested on other data using the same method and it is working too. Now I just need help to find a way to rewrite the first letter of each string whenever they are repeated.

Thank you!

Comment: OK, What is your question? (please don't say *how can I do this*)

Comment: This is a better write-up than your previous question but you should have edited [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837984/replace-repeated-char-with-something-else-in-a-string)

Comment: I would probably look at splitting it on the '\', then from the resultant array look at the first letter of each element to determine what that value represents.  This should give you a starting point.  I guess this was written before the creation of Xml! :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: My previous question helped me with my other part of the program, though I thought it can help me with this one too, but I guess it did not work out.

Comment: @DarrenYoung: Yes, the data was from the 1950s - 1960s, I used the method you recommended, but I ended up having cBlue cRed cWhite in my array. I still need to find a way to distinguish them by changing the c to c2 c3 etc.

Comment: Your string ( `.....\s200mph\....` ) is ambiguous.  where is `\s...` and `\s1...` **:)**

Comment: How would you differentiate between s200 and s2100? Or for that matter oowen?

Comment: Look at the string.insert method for your second part.  Don't forget though that strings are immutable...

Comment: @L.B and abhi : I used DarrenYoung's method by splitting the string just based on "\". The result of that I will have s2100 (say for example) Then I use the substring to query the first 2 char of the string, it will clearly tell me s2 (speed 2) has 100 mph

Comment: @user3320572 But I read `\s200mph` as 3rd speed with value *00 mph*

Comment: @L.B that's my point. Unless it can only have a single variable for Speed.

Comment: Actually you both brought up a good point. I need to discuss with the project owner about this.

Comment: That `\s200mph` string is ambiguous only in isolation. In the context of the entire property string, there is no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @JimMischel How do you interpret this `\s225mph\s235mph\s325mph` `225,35,25` or `235,25,25`? Sorry I must vote -1.

Comment: @L.B. If I were parsing it, I have the context and know which one came first. So the first has no numeric prefix and the others do. The obvious result is `225mph,35mph,25mph`. And if I saw `\s225mph\s395mph` then I would flag an error because the second `\s` should have a '2' numeric prefix and it doesn't.

Comment: @JimMischel `So the first has no numeric prefix` You can read the first item `\s225mph` as *"it has a numeric prefix 2"* You can't be sure that order of items has a meaning (no info in the question). I may read it as first item has a prefix 2 and the second one has not.

Comment: @L.B: Of course I can assume that the order has a meaning. He is converting data that has no numeric prefixes into data that *does* have numeric prefixes. He's *reformatting the data*, which means that he can enforce that order and he'll have to modify the code that parses the data, too. His example shows that the first one has no prefix, and the following items of the same type do. As long as his generation code maintains that (and it's a more than reasonable thing to expect), then *there is no ambiguity.*

Answer (score 0):

I found this an interesting little puzzle to see what I could do with LINQ. The following seems to work:

```
private string FixIt(string foo)
{
    var newFoo = "\\" + string.Join("\\",
        foo.Split(new[] {'\\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .GroupBy(s => s[0],
                (c, g) =>
                {
                    var cnt = 0;
                    return g.Select(x => cnt++ == 0 
                        ? x 
                        : x[0] + cnt.ToString() + x.Substring(1));
                })
            .SelectMany(g => g));
    return newFoo;
}


Input:  \vToyota\cBlue\cRed\cWhite\s200mph\oAndrew\oJohn
Output: \vToyota\cBlue\c2Red\c3White\s200mph\oAndrew\o2John
```

That `SelectMany` is a handy thing to remember.

Comment: Downvoter: Something to share? It's customary to provide a reason when you downvote.

Comment: @L.B: This answer generates the output that the O.P. asked for. Whether or not the output he wanted is ambiguous (and I maintain that it isn't--see my comment) is irrelevant.

Comment: Maybe. You made an assumption about the orders of items and I say I can't see anything related to this in the question. I may be wrong but when writing answers based on assumptions you should be prepared to downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Because I thought this question was interesting I wrote up a program to do what I believe to be a reasonable solution. I started with a few principle assumptions:

- In "old data" situations you probably don't know every single option that is going to show up in the records. Consequently whatever approach is taken needs to quickly and easily accommodate new types of delimiters and tags. For that reason I did *not* use a string.split approach (even though this is easier to read). Instead all tokens are declared at the beginning of the file. **Anything** can be a token whether or not it has a "\" in front of it.
- The solution needs to gracefully handle records that don't conform to the standards
- The option of parsing integers for multiple records needs to be able to be disabled per record type. Speed, for example, doesn't (seem) to be able to appear multiple times per record. So, setting the value for speed to false in the "ALLOW_MULTIPLE" variable turns this parsing off, ensuring the correct output value.

In my solution I also created separate classes for readability and so the code could be quickly investigated. Although I would not suggest that this is production ready, the following should go a long ways towards solving the issue. Best of luck!

```
// Just paste the rest of this into a new console application to see it work!
public class Program
{
    private static readonly List<string> TOKENS = new List<string> {@"\v", @"\c", @"\o", @"\s"};
    private static readonly List<string> DISPLAY = new List<string> {"Vehicle", "Color", "Owner", "Speed"};
    private static readonly List<bool> ALLOW_MULTIPLE = new List<bool> {false, true, true, false};


    private class RecordEntry
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() { return DataType + ": " + Value; }
    }

    private class ParsedRecord
    {
        private List<RecordEntry> entries = new List<RecordEntry>();
        public List<RecordEntry> Entries { get { return entries; } }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // sample records (second has a \m which is ignored since it isn't a recognized token)
        var records = new[] {@"\vToyota\cBlue\c2Red\c3White\s200mph\oAndrew\o2John",
                                  @"\vChevy\c2Orange\cGreen\s50mph\o2Bob\mWhite"};

        var parsedData = new List<ParsedRecord>();
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            // character by character parsing
            var currentParseRecord = new ParsedRecord();
            parsedData.Add(currentParseRecord);

            var currentRecord = new StringBuilder(record);
            var currentToken = new StringBuilder();
            for (var parseIdx = 0; parseIdx < currentRecord.Length; parseIdx++)
            {
                currentToken.Append(currentRecord[parseIdx]);

                var recordIdx = 0;
                var index = TOKENS.IndexOf(currentToken.ToString());
                if (index < 0) continue;

                // current char is used up now (was part of the token)
                parseIdx++;

                if (ALLOW_MULTIPLE[index] && currentRecord.Length > parseIdx + 1)
                {
                    // assuming less than 10 records max - if more, would need to pull multiple numeric values here
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(currentRecord[parseIdx] + "", out recordIdx)) recordIdx = 0;
                    else parseIdx++;
                }

                // find the next token or end of string
                int valueLength = FindNextToken(currentRecord, parseIdx) - parseIdx;
                if (valueLength <= 0) valueLength = currentRecord.Length - parseIdx;

                currentParseRecord.Entries.Add(new RecordEntry
                    {
                        DataType = DISPLAY[index],
                        Index =  recordIdx,
                        Value = currentRecord.ToString(parseIdx, valueLength)
                    });

                parseIdx += valueLength - 1;
                currentToken.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private static int FindNextToken(StringBuilder value, int currentIndex)
    {
        for (var searchIdx = currentIndex; searchIdx < value.Length; searchIdx++) {
            if (TOKENS.Any(checkToken => value.Length > searchIdx + checkToken.Length &&
                                         value.ToString(searchIdx, checkToken.Length) == checkToken)) {
                return searchIdx;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```